# What is maximum size limit of sqlite in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sqlite, core-data

Someone asked me that what is maximum size limit of sqlite and core data in iOS. I had already searched this question but not getting any relevant answer. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of SQLite databases is in the hundreds of terabytes. The only real limit on iOS is the amount of free disk space. SQLite.org has a page about the theoretical limits: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html